# Change kernel device node in Ubuntu 16.04 (static usb interface name based on the port it's plugged in)

Tags: ubuntu, systemd, udev

I'm working with USB network interfaces (Ethernet over USB), on a Raspberry Pi. The goal is basically to flash several Linux machines at the same time through TFTP U-boot, using the four USB ports offered by the Raspberry Pi.

Right now, I've defined four usb interfaces, and each of them has an IP address. I've set up the `tftp` server. It works fine, however if I try to plug several Linux machines at the same time, it seems like DHCP mixes the interfaces (like, old `usb0` becomes new `usb1` and old `usb1` becomes new `usb0`), and I believe it creates confusion in the leases and so the TFTP exchanges seem to get stuck in a soft-locked state.

Well, this can't happen. So I set up four udev rules that give these devices a fixed name, based on the usb port they're plugged in. Something like this :

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ACTION=="add", DEVPATH=="*.2", NAME="usb0"
```

(I got these values using `udevadm info`)

I obviously need to rename the device, since it will be the name of my network interface. So, in this case, a symlink isn't of any use (unless there is something I'm not aware of).

However, `systemd-udevd` doesn't let me rename the device :

> Feb 28 17:25:01 pi systemd-udevd[3749]: NAME="usb2" ignored, kernel device nodes can not be renamed; please fix it 
>   in /lib/udev/rules.d/99-systemd.rules:49

I've read online that this was possible before version 15.04, so I believe there should be a way to restore this old behavior?

Any piece of advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things need to be clarified:

1. There is a tree hierarchy of devices. Your USB Ethernet adapter shows up as **multiple** "devices" in different subsystems, representing different layers:

   - subsystem `usb`, devtype `usb_device` – a USB device connected to some port;
   - subsystem `usb`, devtype `usb_interface` – a specific function that the USB device provides (the term 'interface' has a different meaning than in networking!);
   - subsystem `net` – the actual network interface (this time in the regular networking sense).

   (The net device is a child of the usb_interface, which itself is a child of the usb_device, etc.)
2. Not all devices even have "device nodes," e.g. network interfaces **do not** show up in `/dev`. *(Which is unfortunate, but besides the point.)*
3. Only network interfaces can be renamed. Other devices cannot. This policy became stricter when Linux switched from udev creating device nodes to the kernel itself doing so. (Yes, technically `mv /dev/foo /dev/bar` still works, but the *policy* is that udev will not mess with what the kernel exports.)

So, point #1 is important: your whole post is talking about network interfaces (which belong to the `net` subsystem) but your udev rules are matching against the `usb` subsystem – as a result you're trying to rename some abstract USB device in /sys.

Your rule needs to specifically have `SUBSYSTEM=="net"`. If you want to additionally match parent devices, `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` could be used (note the 'S').